# Update a column by Grouping

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-update

I have table with two columns

```
key     Account
----    -------
AAA01   BGHJ
AAA01   JHGF
AAA01   UHGF
AAA02   IYTG
AAA03   JHKJH
AAA03   REYT
```

I want to update the Key column value with the Account value that is coming up first. So, my output should be as:

```
key    Account
----   -------
BGHJ    BGHJ
BGHJ    JHGF
BGHJ    UHGF
IYTG    IYTG
JHKJH   JHKJH
JHKJH   REYT
```

I have been trying to use the ROW_NUMBER on Account partitioning by 'Key' and trying to update the 'Key' values with Account Value having ROW_NUMBER=1. But this is somehow not working.

**Updated test data:**

```
key     Account
----    -------
1G00N   1N000C
1G00N   1N0008
1G00N   1N253M
1G00N   1N253N
1G00C   1N253N
1G00C   1N000B
```

I want to update the Key column value with the Account value that is coming up first. So, my output should be as:

```
key     Account
----    -------
1N000C  1N000C
1N000C  1N0008
1N000C  1N253M
1N000C  1N253N
1N253N  1N253N
1N253N  1N000B
```

Comment: What's the database (and its version)? PostgreSQL, MariaDB, H2, Sybase, etc.

Comment: The database is SQLServer.

Comment: The first three rows of the last example should update with `1N0008`, not `1N000C`. The first goes previous to the latter according to alphanumeric ordering. Remember that in a RDBMS rows don't have specific ordering unless you specify it while querying.

Comment: You are right. When MIN() is used, 1N0008 is getting considered as the 'Key'. But  I am looking for the output to show 1N000C as it is the first account number occuring. MIN() is not helping in this case. Is there any other option to get 1N000C? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ah... OK. In a RDBMS table rows do not -- I repeat DO NOT -- have inherent ordering. When you say "...as it is the first account number occuring..." it just doesn't make sense. Do you follow? In simple words, a database table is not an Excel sheet and doesn't have a "row number" or anything similar.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a select which would generate this output:

```
SELECT
    MIN(Account) OVER (PARTITION BY "key") AS "key",
    Account
FROM yourTable;
```

[image]

### Demo

A general update query which would work on most databases might be:

```
UPDATE yourTable t1
SET "key" = (SELECT MIN(t2.Account) FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2."key" = t1."key");
```

Comment: Thank you. But MIN() isn't working if the 'Account' has some alphanumeric characters. Is there any way to update it based on the first occurance rather than MIN() ?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: It's SQLServer.

Comment: @Chandra I added a demo to my answer, which seems to be working on SQL Server.  If your real data differs from what you posted, then you might want to update your question with that data.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I have updated the correct format of the data I am using. With the MIN() I am getting as:                                                                    
 Key           Account                                                                                                             1N000B 1N253N
1N000B 1N000B
1N0008 1N000C
1N0008 1N0008
1N0008 1N253M
1N0008 1N253N

Comment: @Chandra It should update with `1N0008`, not `1N000C`. The first goes previous to the latter according to alphanumeric ordering.

Answer (score 0):

something like this might work:

`UPDATE TABLE A
SET A.KEY = (SELECT TOP 1 B.ACCOUNT FROM TABLE B WHERE B.KEY = A.KEY)`

Comment: Note that `TOP 1` without an `ORDER BY` clause might not work as expected.  And `TOP` is only supported by SQL Server and Access.